# Problem converting a GMT date to local time using C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-mobile, compact-framework, timezone

We have a Windows Mobile application written in C# (compact framework). Regional setting is set to (English) New Zealand. Time zone is set to GMT+12 New Zealand.

We store our dates in GMT/UTC format.
We have a date 2010-02-18 18:00:00 in UTC

This time in New Zealand is 7:00 am.

When we call on a datetime object

```
starttime = starttime.ToLocalTime();
```

we get 9:00 am.
What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that `starttime` is indeed in GMT?

Comment: If your time zone is GMT+12, should *18.00 h* not result in *6.00 h the following day*? Neither 7.00h nor 9.00 h seem to be the *correct* answer. *(confused...)*

Comment: @Treb: I guess NZ is on summer time in mid February. Weird...

Comment: @Treb I am confused too, I don't know how to properly convert an UTC date to localtime. The GMT+12 New Zealand option is available by drop-down in the Time setting of the Windows Mobile device.

Comment: @Zach I verified it's indeed in GMT. For my local timezone works great, we are having problems with NZ.

Comment: @Pentium 10, @Remus Rusanu: I think Remus is on the right track here. On the northern hemisphere we are in **winter** (indeed, I can see snow when I look out the window ;-), but on the southern hemisphere it is **summer** right now, so *summer time* or *daylight saving* is most probably the cause of my *off by one error*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you specified the "kind" on that datetime? Something like this:

```
DateTime parsedStartTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(
    DateTime.Parse(starttime),
    DateTimeKind.Utc);

DateTime localStartTime = parsedStartTime.DateToLocalTime();
```

That might help as it might not know that the datetime you have now is in the type of Utc (it is probably unspecified).

If that doesn't help maybe some of your code showing how you are setting starttime would help.

Comment: I added DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal to our ParseExact method and works fine.